# Gödel's Completeness Theorem: Did Gödel show how to construct derivations?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Gödel's Completeness Theorem for first-order logic states that there is a proof system with a finite number of rules and axioms that is both sound and complete for first-order logic: that there exists a derivation within such a proof system for all valid statement from first-order logic.

My question is: did Gödel merely prove *that* there exists *some* such a derivation, or did Gödel's proof show *what* such a derivation would actually look like, i.e. *how* to derive any valid statement?

Of course, given the truth of the Completeness Theorem, we can always obtain a derivation as follows: systematically iterate through all possible derivations (which is possible, since the set of derivations is enumerable), and if the statement is valid, then eventually we'll run into a derivation for it.

However, pointing to such an algorithm will of course not prove that there is a derivation. So, I was wondering if maybe Gödel had an algorithm that he pointed to and for which he proved that it would always create a derivation of any valid statement.  Or, at the very least: does Gödel's proof naturally translate itself into such an algorithm?

If not, is there a well-known alternative proof of the Completeness Theorem that does provide such an algorithmic proof?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel%27s_completeness_theorem#Proofs

Comment: @J.G. Yeah, I saw that, and I also went to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_proof_of_G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem but I couldn't quite figure it out from there ... it doesn't *look* like he is producing an algorithm ...

Comment: You may want to look at the [semantic (or analytic) tableau approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux).

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Yes, that;'s exactly what I was thinking: it seems like  we should be able to make that into an algorithmic proof ... do you know if anyone has actually done that? Also, any tableaux can be converted into a more traditional natural deduction style proof ... so even before these tableaux were around, I am thinking someone must have had the insight to effectively use the basic method of tableaux (one big proof by contradiciton, and then just exploring al possible options for satisfiability) in a more traditional style proof ... who was the first to think of this?

Comment: Perhaps, you want to take a look at Melvin Fitting's *First-Order Logic and Automated Theorem Proving*, Springer 1996?  A naive implementation of the semantic tableau approach for first-order logic does not guarantee that the tableau will be closed whenever it's possible, but there ways to obviate that.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Right ...  I know the algorithm, and hence the proof, would not be trivial ... which is exactly why I was hoping that there would be a recognized 'first' algortihmic proof for completeness. In fact, I had hoped that Godel himself had already done that, but it appears not. Thanks for your feedback BTW!!

Comment: In fact, Chaper V of Smullyan's *First Order Logic* proves the Completeness Theorem by proving that every valid sentence is provable by the tableau method.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Yay! Though I believe Jeffrey's book *Formal Logic: Scope and Limits* was just a little older?

Comment: Smullyan credits Beth and Hintikka, and also a paper by Anderson and Belnap from 1959.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Ooh, the plot thickens ... :)

Comment: Goedel's work is easily accessible. Why are you asking us to filter it for you?

Comment: @RobArthan I asked because I did try and look at his original proof but had too hard of a time understanding it well enough to figure out if it was an algorithmic proof or at least could be transformed into one easily enough.  I guess I'm just not smart enough to comprehend it well enough. But I figured there would be some smart and helpful people on this site that would be able to answer that question for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, the completeness theorem is far from algorithmic. It uses the axion of choice and in fact is equivalent to the ultrafilter lemma, a weaker form of choice.

Comment: OK, thanks ... but there *are* algorithms to construct derivations, assuming derivations exist, right? I mean the 'dumb' brute force method I describe is one such algorithm. But are there more directly algorithmic proofs? If so, who was the first to do so?

Comment: Only needs axiom of choice for uncountable languages, (and I don't think Godel's original version covered uncountable languages).

Comment: @Bram28 The brute force method you described is not an algorithm: if the statement is valid, you'll find a proof, but if the statement is not valid, you will run forever. In fact, there is no algorithm in many cases.

Comment: @Ted I am well aware of that. The 'dumb' brute force method I describe will of course run forever if the statement is not valid. And yet, for all the valid ones I will eventually get a derivation.  I am wondering if there are more efficient ways to produce a derivation for the valid ones, even if that way will sometimes run forever for the invalid ones. If you don't want to call that an algorithm, ok, let's just call it a set of instructions then.

Comment: @Bram28 you may be refrring to automatic theorem provers. This is a very active area of research.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I think you still need something like countable choice even for finite languages.

Comment: @IttayWeiss That's one way of putting it .. but I am still looking for a mathematical proof: is there a proof that points to a theorem prover and says: Yes, it's complete (i.e. it will always produce a proof for any valid statement) and here is why (without already assuming the truth of the completeness result)

Comment: @Ittay I don’t think so (also countable choice can fail under the ultrafilter lemma).

Comment: Ittay, you do not need choice if the language is well-ordered. In particular, you do not need it for finite language. In the context of reverse mathematics you need the Weak König's Lemma (WKL0), which essentially states that the Cantor space is compact (note that in this context all languages are countable). [Also pinging @spaceisdarkgreen for context.]